# Only Catch Importerrors Caused Directly by Import

Tags: python, error-handling, python-import

I have a situation where a python file is dynamically loaded with the `importlib` module. I then catch `ImportError` to detect if the file does not exist. However this catches any `importerrors` indirectly caused by the import too. E.g.

```
# file a.py
import importlib

try:
    importlib.load_module("b")
except ImportError:
    print("it seems b.py does not exist!")  # oops! it actually does, it just also raised an ImportError!

# file b.py

import nonexistantmoduletocauserror
```

I would like to be able to tell the difference between an `ImportError` caused from my `importlib.load_module` and and caused by the process of executing the imported module itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load_module()` is deprecated now.  They say to use `exec_module()` instead.  And indeed this offers a solution, because the import now happens in two phases: finding the module, then executing it.  See "Checking if a module can be imported" in the documentation, here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#checking-if-a-module-can-be-imported

In your case the code would look like:

```
spec = importlib.util.find_spec('b')
if spec is None:
    print("it seems b.py does not exist!")
else:
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create and use a custom exception:

File `MyImportError.py`:

```
class MyImportError(Exception):
    """Raise for my specific kind of exception"""
```

File `a.py`:

```
from MyImportError import MyImportError
import importlib

try:
    importlib.import_module("b")
except MyImportError:
    print("Error: It seems b.py does not exist!")
```

File `b.py`:

```
from MyImportError import MyImportError

try:
    import nonexistantmoduletocauserror
except ImportError:
    raise MyImportError("Error: It seems nonexistantmoduletocauserror.py does not exist!")
```

---

**Edit:**

Okay, I see, then try that alternatively:

File `a.py`:

```
import traceback
import sys
import importlib

try:
    importlib.import_module("b")
except ImportError as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(exc_type)
    print(exc_obj)
    traceback.print_exc()
```

File `b.py`:

```
import nonexistantmoduletocauserror
```

You will see a full traceback with the relevant error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darius/code/python/sklearn-keras/examples/a.py", line 8, in <module>
    importlib.import_module("b")
  File "/Users/darius/anaconda2/envs/sklearn-keras/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/darius/code/python/sklearn-keras/examples/b.py", line 3, in <module>
    import nonexistantmoduletocauserror
ImportError: No module named nonexistantmoduletocauserror

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
No module named nonexistantmoduletocauserror
```

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately it is not feasible to wrap everything that might cause an importError in a try-except clause. Especially since the modules will be provided by third parties.

Comment: I add a alternative solution, maybe it's more useful.